# Unknown format file is downloaded when url is accessed

Tags: linux, cpanel, godaddy

I have migrated my website to a linux server. Before it was working fine but now when ever I try to access my website an unknown format file is downloaded every time. I tried to change permissions from Cpanel but nothing happened.

You can also look at [falaktextile.com](http://falaktextile.com).

Thank you.

Comment: The server serves the php file instead of executing it. You should tell apache to execute php. One way to do this is to install and enable mod_php. How to do this depends on your linux distribution.

Answer (score 1):

On Debian style distros (Debian, Ubuntu, etc.), you need to:

```
apt-get update
apt-get install php5
/etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

After that, your php code gets executed on the server side and html will be returned to browser.

On RedHat style distros (Fedora, CentOS, etc.), you need to:

```
yum install php5
service apache2 restart
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need to either reinstall PHP or ensure your Apache configuration is setup correctly. It's outputting your actual PHP code rather than executing it. Depending on distro, you can run `dpkg-reconfigure php5`